# How to prove that this is NP complete

Tags: graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np, correctness-proof

I have the following problem: Given an undirected graph with n vertices v1,…,vn, a positive integer weight on each edge, and a n×n symmetric matrix Rij. The objective is to find a subset S of the edges such that the total cost of the edges in S is minimized and for every pair of vertices vi and vj there exist at least Rij disjoint paths from vi to vj such that all paths use only edges in S.

I tried showing a reduction from Undirected Hamiltonian Cycle as follows, but I'm not quite sure where to go from there. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem cannot be NP complete since it is not a decision problem, and hence it does not belong to NP. The decision version of your problem (given an edge-weighted graph $G$, the matrix $R$, and an integer $k$, is there a set of edges that satisfies the constraints in your question and has a total cost at most $k$?) is clearly in NP.

To show that the problem is NP-hard you can reduce from the (decision version of the) minimum Steiner tree problem (to the decision version of your problem). The graph and the weights are the same. Build $R$ as follows: for each pair $v_i, v_j$ of terminals set $R_{i,j}=1$, then set all other entries of $R$ to $0$.

The set of edges of any Steiner tree is clearly also a solution to your problem (and the costs coincide). Moreover, any set of edges that is a solution to your problem must induce a graph having a connected component that contains all the terminals. This implies the existence of a Steiner tree that costs at most as much as the sum of the weights of the selected edges.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i can only reduce from the following: VERTEX COVER, SET COVER, INDEPENDENT SET, 3-SAT, HAMILTONIAN CYCLE, and HAMILTONIAN PATH, TRAVELING SALESMAN PROBLEM, 3-DIMENSIONAL MATCHING